# Changing default slug of post to the post id

Tags: rewrite-rules

Is it possible to change the default slug from the post title to a number?

For example, the current url to a blog post would be:

**baseurl/blog/the-title-of-the-post**

Lets say the id of the post is 2234, I want the url to be like this:

**baseurl/blog/2234**

EDIT: made post more generic to wordpress and not a plugin

Comment: Welcome to WordPress Development. Questions specific to Third Party products are off-topic. Read the [faq].

Comment: Check this solution: [Rewrite URI](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33551/how-to-rewrite-uri-of-custom-post-type/33555#33555)

Comment: ManojKumar, I've tried it. @Mayeenul-islam this question could easily apply if I wanted the sam functionality for post type items. I can re-phrase.

Comment: @paxamus what happen if you change it to a custom URL: baseurl/blog`/%post_id%/`

Comment: @MayeenulIslam okay, that does work, for blog posts. As for my other issue I will have to ask another community.