# WooCommerce Product URL re-writing

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to re-write my WooCommerce product urls to be have the Post ID at the end, like this:

/product/product-name-**post-id**/

I've used the code from this thread [How to rewrite URI of custom post type?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33551/how-to-rewrite-uri-of-custom-post-type/) which is working, but we have /product/post-id-product-name/.

```
add_filter('post_type_link', 'wpse33551_post_type_link', 1, 3);

function wpse33551_post_type_link( $link, $post = 0 ){
    if ( $post->post_type == 'product' ){
        return home_url( 'product/' . $post->post_name . '-' . $post->ID );
    } else {
        return $link;
    }
}

add_action( 'init', 'wpse33551_rewrites_init' );

function wpse33551_rewrites_init(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'product/([0-9]+)?$',
        'index.php?post_type=product&p=$matches[1]',
        'top' );
}
```

I can't work out how to work the re-write rule in the second function here to get the Post-ID to be at the end?

Comment: Have you flushed your permalinks after setting this ? The code looks good for the permalink part. To flush permalinks, go to Settings > Permalinks and just hit the "save" button.

Comment: Yes! The code works ... BUT ... it's backwards, and I believe it is this part that in the add_rewrite_rule is the culprit:

 'product/([0-9]+)?$',

It's giving the format /product/id-postname/ but I would like it to go /product/postname-id/.

Comment: i don't understand what you want. URL is ok, but you have 404 on front ? have a look to this plugin that can help you understand what does do your rewrite rules https://wordpress.org/plugins/rewrite-rules-inspector/

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```php
add_action( 'init', 'wpse33551_rewrites_init' );

function wpse33551_rewrites_init(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'product/.+\-([0-9]+)?$',
        'index.php?post_type=product&p=$matches[1]',
        'top' );
}
```

The filter function is changing the permalink to like `product/my-product-name-88`. You just need to tweak the regex in the second function to deal with that pattern.

The regex is:

`product/` – matches the literal string `product/`

`.+` – matches one or more other characters

`\-` – matches a hyphen (the backslash escapes it, so the regex engine doesn't think it's a special regex operator, like in the next bit)

`([0-9]+)?$` – matches and captures one or more numbers at the end of the URL

As [@gregory](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/139936/gregory) says, after making this change you need to click the save button on your permalink page `wp-admin/options-permalink.php` to flush the rewrite cache.